# What is a good location to publish my research in a public setting?

Tags: publishing, research

First and foremost, I do believe this is an appropriate question for this site, but my apologies if not!

My class has been asked to publish our individual research papers in a public setting. In a minimum of one paragraph we are to present our work, be it in a relevant blog, as a Wikipedia entry related to our research topic, magazine, local newspaper, scholarship site, contest, and any other sort of relevant outlet.

Regrettably, I'm entirely unsure of where I might go about posting something in regards to my own topic, and I was wondering if anyone had some ideas.

Below is my abstraction and thesis.

---

**Thesis:** Google has bettered the world by offering these within the implementation of its business model, contributions and innovations in computer products and services, and its attention to researching and developing products guided towards the future.

**Abstract:** Google has been able to succeed in a market that had already been largely filled with competitors that had a considerable foothold by using advertising as a revenue generator. By innovating and making itself a sole provider of certain services, and offering alternatives to those already available that were of high quality, Google has been able to acquire an immense user base to fuel the effectiveness of its advertising platform, adwords. As a direct result of these things, Google has acted as a stellar example of what innovation can produce. Increasing the standard quality of software available to the public for free, it has resulted in a raised standard of software, and that the mindset to innovate and bring something new and useful to the market can allow some corporations to thrive. Google[x] has implemented several future oriented projects, those being the Loon and Contact Lens projects. Google Loon and Google Contact Lens are examples of such, Google Loon to give internet access to people in rural and remote areas, provide service in coverage gaps, and to people after disasters, and Contact Lens to allow diabetics glucose monitoring in the form of a contact lens. Google’s products and services, researching and developing towards the future, and its business model have factors that have bettered the world.

---

Thank you!

Comment: I believe http://academia.stackexchange.com/ might provide more helpful answers.

Comment: The best place to publish this depends on what the purpose of that publication is. Are you supposed to get reader reactions? Instigate a discussion? And who are you writing this for? That's what you need to think about: purpose and target audience, and then I'm sure then the proper context will become apparent. Just writing to have something written and post it to have it published are useless exercises.

Comment: Purpose and target audience, that bit helped me well in finding a place to go and send it off to. I ended up sending it off to CNet as a sort of last resort, but in the future that'll help, I'm sure! I'll have to go check out that other stackexchange as well!

Thank you for both your answers, SF and @What

Answer (score 1):

From the statement of your question, it seems that you are only
supposed to make public a summary of your work, since you can
hardly be expected to publish a whole paper in a blog, or even less in
a wikipedia article. Furthermore, you are stating that you are
required to publish a minimum of one paragraph.

Thus by asking your question as you did, with the text to be
published, on a public site such as this one, it appears to me that
you did fulfill your class obligation. Your text is indeed public.  I,
and other people, may disagree with some of it, but this is
immaterial. So, as an answer to your question, I suggest that you have
nothing more to do.

It can only be regretted that you did not ask your question 40 days
earlier. It is an interesting one in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Publish it into one of the open access journals for research papers.

Do some search, there are some alternatives. try to get into a peer-reviewed scholarly journal if possible.

This could be important in your future if you want to go to graduate school and could greatly help your chances to get in.